# Sum values from dataframe with iloc

Tags: python

--Edited--

I am following this script found on Kaggle on multilabel-category-prediction : https://www.kaggle.com/rodsaldanha/multilabel-category-prediction

I am currently at the command line 344, which is part of exploratory analysis section :

```
bar_plot = pd.DataFrame()
bar_plot['cat'] = description_category.columns[1:]
bar_plot['count'] = description_category.iloc[:,1:].sum().values
bar_plot.sort_values(['count'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
bar_plot.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
bar_plot.head()
```

The output should look like this :

```
    cat                     count
0   International Movies    1927
1   Dramas                  1623
2   Comedies                1113
3   International TV Shows  1001
4   Documentaries           668
```

However, I am having this error for that specific part of the command :

```
  bar_plot['count'] = description_category.iloc[:,1:].sum().values
```

The error is below

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-76549b4c5547> in <module>
----> 1 bar_plot['count'] = description_category.iloc[:,1:].sum().values
C:\Anaconda\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3117         else:
   3118             # set column
-> 3119             self._set_item(key, value)
   3120 
   3121     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):
C:\Anaconda\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3192 
   3193         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3194         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3195         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3196 
C:\Anaconda\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3389 
   3390             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3391             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3392             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3393                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:
C:\Anaconda\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
   3999 
   4000     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 4001         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   4002 
   4003     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

How can I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: You have not ask a question.

Comment: You need to give a simple example from your data set to let anyone who wants to help you re-create the problem and provide the correct fix.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with sample input and your expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @Timus : didn't work   (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str)

Comment: @Etienne I've realized that I was not on point. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer wasn't on point. After looking at it again, I have the suspicion that your dataframe `description_category` has at least one column over which you can't sum, and therefore `.sum()` creates a result that doesn't match the requiered length. I think you're running into a scenario like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [5, 6], 'D': [7, '8']})
```

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  3  5  7
1  2  4  6  8
```

In `df` you can't sum over column `D`, here because there are items in it that have types that can't be summed (`int` and `str`). In your case there could be other reasons, i.e. a column has elements of a type which isn't summable at all (like `dict` etc.)

If you look at

```
print(df.columns[1:])
print(df.iloc[:, 1:].sum().values)
```

you'll get something like

```
Index(['B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
[ 7, 11]
```

two objects of different length! `.sum` just ignores column `D`, because it can't sum up it's elements, and doesn't complain about it.

Now if you try something similar to what you were doing

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new['col_1'] = df.columns[1:]
try:
    df_new['col_2'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum().values
except ValueError as val_err:
    print(val_err)
```

you'll get something like

```
ValueError('Length of values (2) does not match length of index (3)')
```

which is pretty much the error message that you get.

Remedy: Hard to tell. First look at `description_category.columns[1:]` and `description_category.iloc[:,1:].sum().values` to confirm that this is actually happening. Then locate the columns/data in `description_category` which lead to the problem. Afterwards go back through the data generating process and determine how this came about. Or try directly to transform the columns that cause the problem. The data for the kaggle project don't seem to be available any more: Where are your data from?

Comment: Hi Timus, I will try your recommendations and let you know. In the meantime, here is the link to the data for this project : https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows

Comment: Hi again, actually, there was two issues : 1) the database contained new data (generating new columns) which were not there when the script was build in the first place (so I was missing a part of the data). 2) The second one relate to the command #342. The "category" columns (1-2-3), which in the script appear at the begining the original script, appeared at the end on mine. So, on the command #343, I needed to adjust the index in order to make it stop before these column. So, you were right, there was column with data that could not sum up. This being said, many thanks again!